# How to return two strings in one return statement in java?

Tags: java

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public TblSeed getSeed(String tableName, String tableName1) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        List<TblSeed> list = new ArrayList<TblSeed>();
        TblSeed tblSeed = null;
        try{
            Query query = session.createQuery("from TblSeed where seedName =:tableName");
            query.setParameter("tableName", tableName);
            Query query1 = session
                .createQuery("from TblSeed where seedName =:tableName1");
            query.setParameter("tableName1", tableName1);
            list = query.list();
            if (list!=null && list.size()>0) {
                tblSeed = list.get(0);
            }
            list = query1.list();
            if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                tblSeed = list.get(0);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            tblSeed = null;
            logger.error("Exception:",ex);
        }
        return tblSeed;

}
```

Error- I am getting the error that the parameter tableName1 couldn't locate while returning tblSeed.

Plz tell me how can i get this ?

Comment: Q: Is your question "How to return two strings in one return statement?", or is it "Why I am getting the error that the parameter tableName1 couldn't locate while returning tblSeed?"  Q: Does your database have a "TblSeed" table? A"seedName" column?   Most important: Q: *WHAT IS THE EXACT ERROR*???  Please copy/paste the full error text, and the line# it's occurring.

Comment: Ya.. I have a TblSeed and where i have got seed name as a column. Here i am passing the two seed names as tableName and tableName1. Ans while returning the value through tblSeed i am getting the error that "Could not locate the parameter tableName1"..

Comment: We might actually be able to follow the code if you fix the indentations.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is rather cryptic and the question is off topic to the problem. However this is the issue you got. You are executing two Hibernate queries as query and query1. Also specify the **stacktrace** always posting the question.

The erroneous line is

```
query.setParameter("tableName1", tableName1);
```

Make changes it as:

```
query1.setParameter("tableName1", tableName1);
```